# BINDing an ASP.NET 2.0 FormView - CheckBox or RadioButton to Oracle CHAR(1) Y/N

Tags: asp.net-2.0

Oracle 9i has not BOOLEAN data type. CheckBoxes in ASP.NET are BOOLEAN controls are they not?

So using a CHAR(1) column with Y or N values in the Oracle table, how do I bind to a CheckBox or CheckBoxList or RadioButton or RadioButtonList control on an ASP.NET 2.0 web form?

I'm using VB, 'specially since I'm a noobie.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the value to 1 or 0 and have an int datatype